# Include a more descriptive message when accounts are deleted on the effected accounts that have rep removed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, notifications

Question is a bit of a mouthful but I see users that are dismayed by the drop in their rep and got to thinking if it would be possible to display a more appropriate message instead of just "user removed" and a -10 in their reputation section of their user page.

Perhaps just the text of the user account that was deleted and what question it pertained to?

Comment: Revealing who voted or what question(s) the vote(s) were on would violate the anonymity of voting.

Comment: oops sorry I have gold tag in Discussion so I dropped the dupe hammer. Not sure that's exactly appropriate here... discussion tag didn't even belong on this q

Comment: I mean I'm sure it's a dupe, but perhaps others would have liked an opinion

Comment: @KateGregory you can use the same power to reopen, the question will still be linked in the right sidebar.

Comment: @KateGregory - thanks I couldn't find this when I searched.